# Listview not adding 100th item from arraylist in android?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, adapter

I have arraylist.Size of arraylist is 156.when I am running for loop it's running 156 times and it's adding all values into another arraylist.But when I am setting this arraylist into adapter adapter taking 156 items but when I am setting adapter into listview that time Listview taking only 98 items only.

When I am debugging I seen arralist size 156.and arraylist deviding into sets like

0-99
100-199
200-210

see below image :

[image]

Here my adapter taking only 0-99 items.How I can add 100-199 set Items into Listview.

Edit #1:

Adapter class :

```
public class AllserversListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

    Activity mActivity;
    ArrayList<AllServers> mAllServersArray;
    private static LayoutInflater mInflater = null;
    ArrayList<MyFavorites> mFavoriteServers;

    public AllserversListAdapter(Activity activity,
            ArrayList<AllServers> allServers,
            ArrayList<MyFavorites> favoriteServers) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        mActivity = activity;
        mAllServersArray = allServers;

        mFavoriteServers = favoriteServers;

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mAllServersArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    ViewHolder holder;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View vi = convertView;

        if (vi == null) {

            /****** Inflate list items layout file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.servers_list_items, null);

            /****** View Holder Object to contain list items file elements ******/

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.serverName = (TextView) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.server_items_country_name_textview);
            holder.speed = (TextView) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.server_items_speed_textview);
            holder.speedTitleTextView = (TextView) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.speed_title_textview);
            holder.flag = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.server_flag_image);
            holder.star = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.server_items_star);
            holder.bodyLayout = (LinearLayout) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.servere_items_boady_layout);
            holder.speedBackgroundLayout = (LinearLayout) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.speed_backround_layout);
            holder.itemsParentLayout = (LinearLayout) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.server_list_items_parentlayout);
            holder.itemsParentLayout.setBackgroundColor(mActivity
                    .getResources().getColor(R.color.light_gray));
            holder.bodyLayout.setBackgroundColor(mActivity.getResources()
                    .getColor(R.color.dark_gray_black));
            holder.star.setOnClickListener(this);
            /************ Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            vi.setTag(holder);

            holder.star.setTag(position);
            holder.flag.setTag(position);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }
        String ip = mAllServersArray.get(position).getIp();

        String country = mAllServersArray.get(position).getCountry();
        String region = mAllServersArray.get(position).getRegion();
        String speed = mAllServersArray.get(position).getSpeed();
        String flagCountryCode = mAllServersArray.get(position)
                .getCountrycode();

        int ipSpeed = Integer.valueOf(speed);


            holder.speedTitleTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.speed.setText("TimeOut");
            holder.speed.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
            holder.speed.setPadding(26, 0, 26, 0);
            holder.speedBackgroundLayout.setBackgroundColor(mActivity
                    .getResources().getColor(R.color.time_out_color));

        holder.serverName.setText(country + "\n" + region + "\n" + ip);

        return vi;
    }
}
```

Adding items into arraylist :

Any one give me suggest.

Comment: can you please post code?

Comment: off adapter or adding items into arraylist?

Comment: if you gave whole code i think which is better to solve your problem as soon.

Comment: The "divided into sets thing" is something Eclipse's debugger does, not something your program does. It does that so you don't have to scroll through all the entries if you want to find a specific one.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post the code where you are adding items from one list to another and AllserversListAdapter object creation and passing to ListView. Did you check the values and size of  mAllServersArray in adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

```
public class AllserversListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<AllServers> allServers;
    ArrayList<MyFavorites> favoriteServers;

    public AllserversListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<AllServers> allServers,ArrayList<MyFavorites> favoriteServers) {
        this.context = context;
        this.allServers = allServers;
        this.favoriteServers = favoriteServers;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mAllServersArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mAllServersArray.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.servers_list_items, null);
            holder.serverName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.server_items_country_name_textview);
            holder.speed = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.server_items_speed_textview);
            holder.speedTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.speed_title_textview);
            holder.flag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.server_flag_image);
            holder.star = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.server_items_star);
            holder.bodyLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.servere_items_boady_layout);
            holder.speedBackgroundLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.speed_backround_layout);
            holder.itemsParentLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.server_list_items_parentlayout);
            holder.itemsParentLayout.setBackgroundColor(mActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.light_gray));
            holder.bodyLayout.setBackgroundColor(mActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_gray_black));
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        String ip = mAllServersArray.get(position).getIp();

        holder.speedTitleTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.speed.setText("TimeOut");
        holder.speed.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
        holder.speed.setPadding(26, 0, 26, 0);
        holder.speedBackgroundLayout.setBackgroundColor(mActivity
                .getResources().getColor(R.color.time_out_color));

        holder.serverName.setText(mAllServersArray.get(position).getCountry() + "\n" + mAllServersArray.get(position).getRegion() + "\n" + ip);

        holder.flag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // try use (position) value to check which list item click.
            }
        });
        holder.star.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // try use (position) value to check which list item click.
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView serverName;
        TextView speed;
        TextView speedTitleTextView;
        ImageView flag;
        ImageView star;
        LinearLayout bodyLayout;
        LinearLayout speedBackgroundLayout;
        LinearLayout itemsParentLayout;
    }

}
```

Comment: actually in app I am using Customlistview(NestedListView) and I am adding this listview inside scrollview.Actually I want to scroll my entire layout with lisview that's why I added listview inside scrollview.I think this is the problem when I am scrolling this my entire scrollview data scrolling and nestedlistview getview() is not calling. How I can solve this?

Comment: first of all you can not put listview inside scroll view.